# how to insert image into popup in leaflet.css

Tags: drupal-7, mapping, leaflet

I'm needing an image to show on all my Drupal 7 leaflet map popups, below the content that it is pulling in from the drupal nodes. I have added the image test.jpg to my libraries/leaflet/images folder, and the following code to leaflet.css, though its not working.  How can I correct/ do this?

```
.leaflet-popup-tip {
    background: black;
        width: 725px; 
        background-image: url('../images/test.jpg');
    box-shadow: 0 3px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background: black;
        width: 725px; 
        background-image: url('../images/test.jpg');
    box-shadow: 0 3px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately though that didn't make any changes.